# SSD Randomly Filling up. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ssd, disk-usage

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on my Laptop. It's installed on a 100 GB EXT4 partition on my SSD. In the past two weeks I have been encountering this weird problem where I get random notifications that my harddrive is full.

The sum total of all the files in this partition is less than 20 GB. The last time I encountered the same problem I tried using Disk Manager to see where all this space was being used up; I found nothing. I didn't have the time to read up and fix it last time so I didn't use Ubuntu for a few days.

When I rebooted it the next time all was in order. This time my Unity Lens and search is irresponsive and not showing any results. Files (default) and Nemo both refuse to launch as well.

How to fix this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `df [mountpoint]` and `du -cxB 1 [mountpoint]`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the most interesting fact, *what is the make and model of your SSD*? I've installed a lot of different SSDs in various systems but *only one does make this type of problem*, a *OCZ Agility 2* with *Sandforce* controller. Your problem is very likely to be hardware related. One solution could be to update your SSD firmware, but this comes with the not so unlikely risk to lose all your data, that's why i haven't done it. If it's the same problem like my ssd has, than the used disk space should be normal after a reboot?